# How do I modify push_back to store unique vectors

Tags: c++, templates, vector, unique

I'm very very new to vectors and templates. Can't seem to wrap my head around them just yet.
The code is as follows:

```
template <class T>
class m_vector
{
    int m_iNextIndex;
    int m_iMaxSize;
    T* m_pArray;

public:

    m_vector()
    {
        m_pArray = 0;
        init();
    }

    m_vector(const m_vector<T>& other)
    {
        m_pArray = 0;
        m_iNextIndex = 0;
        m_iMaxSize = 0;
        *this = other;
    }

    ~m_vector()
    {
        if (m_pArray != 0)
            delete [] m_pArray;
    }

    void init()
    {
        m_iMaxSize = VECT_INC_SIZE;
        m_pArray = new T[m_iMaxSize];
        m_iNextIndex = 0;
    }

    inline void push_back(const T& item)
    {
        if (m_iNextIndex >= m_iMaxSize)
        {
            resize(m_iNextIndex + VECT_INC_SIZE);
            m_iNextIndex -= VECT_INC_SIZE;
        }
        m_pArray[m_iNextIndex] = item;
        ++m_iNextIndex;
    }

    void resize(int iNewSize)
    {
        if (iNewSize >= m_iMaxSize)
        {
            T* temp = new T[iNewSize];
            for (int i = 0; i < m_iNextIndex; ++i)
            {
                temp[i] = m_pArray[i];
            }
            delete [] m_pArray;
            m_pArray = temp;
            m_iMaxSize = iNewSize;
        }
        m_iNextIndex = iNewSize;
    }

};
```

The push_back is called with Vectors that are (x, y) and rectangles that are (x, y, width, height).
I thought that since the code had "m_pArray[m_iNextIndex] = item" that I could simply add a new function to check that the item is unique before adding it to the vector list. So I coded a routine as follows:

```
int inline exists(const &item)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < m_iMaxSize; i++)
  {
    if(m_pArray[i] == item)
      return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The compiler was non to happy. It reported the following error on the if statement:
“left operand must be a pointer or pointer to class member, or arithmetic”

I'm thinking that I probably need something like:

```
if (type == vector)
 if( (m_pArray[i].x == item.x) ....)
else
 if( (m_pArray[i].x == item.x) && (m_pArray[i].width == item.width) )
```

Am I on the right track?
If so, how do I check the type of item.

Thx, Bill.

Comment: `exists(const &item)`

Comment: Can you show us how you are using your class?

Comment: Please copy the full error message.

Comment: When I compile the provided code, the first error I get is `ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'item' with no type` (c.f. the comment by bipll). Once I addressed that and the lack of a definition for `VECT_INC_SIZE`, the code compiled. While it is good to minimize the code in a [mre], the example still needs to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The issue is likely caused by the `Vector` and `Rectangle` classes not having equality comparison operators. E.g. `friend bool operator==(Vector& lhs, Vector& rhs);`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `Vector` or `Rectangle` are missing a comparison operator e.g.

```
friend bool operator== (Vector const& lhs, Vector const& rhs){
    return lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y;
}
```

But the rest of you code is not good and needs a rewrite. I've rewritten my code to old-old style:

**NOTE: DON'T BLINDLY COPY THIS CODE. ITS JUST FOR REFERENCE. TEST BEFORE YOU USE**

```
#define VECT_INC_SIZE 10

// replaced by iterator version
//template< class InputIt, class Size, class OutputIt>
//OutputIt copy_n(InputIt first, Size count, OutputIt result) {
//    while (count-- > 0) {
//        *result++ = *first++;
//    }
//    return result;
//}

template<class InputIt, class OutputIt>
OutputIt copy(InputIt first, InputIt last, OutputIt d_first) {
    while (first != last) {
        *d_first++ = *first++;
    }
    return d_first;
}

template<class T>
T exchange(T& obj, T new_value)
{
    T old_value = obj;
    obj = new_value;
    return old_value;
}

template <class T>
class m_vector
{
private:
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned int capacity;
    T* array;

public:
    m_vector()
    : size(0)
    , capacity(VECT_INC_SIZE)
    , array(new T[VECT_INC_SIZE])
    {}

    m_vector(m_vector<T> const& other)
    : size(other.size)
    , capacity(other.capacity)
    , array(new T[other.capacity]) {
        //copy_n(other.array, size, array);
        copy(other.cbegin(), other.cend(), begin());
    }

    // rule of 3
    m_vector& operator=(m_vector<T> const& other) {
        if (&other != this) {
            if (other.capacity != capacity){
                delete [] exchange(array, new T[other.capacity]);
                capacity = other.capacity;
            }
            size = other.size;
            //copy_n(other.array, size, array);
            copy(other.cbegin(), other.cend(), begin());
        }
        return *this;
    }

    ~m_vector() {
        if (array != 0) delete [] array;
    }


    void push_back(T const& item) {
        if (size >= capacity) {
            reserve(capacity + VECT_INC_SIZE);
        }
        array[size] = item;
        ++size;
    }

    void reserve(unsigned int newCapacity) {
        if (size > capacity) {
            T* const temp = new T[newCapacity];
            //copy_n(array, size, temp);
            copy(cbegin(), cend(), temp);
            delete [] exchange(array, temp);
            capacity = newCapacity;
        }
    }

    bool exists(T const& item) const {
        //for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        //    if(array[i] == item) return true;
        //}
        for(T const* it = cbegin(); it != cend(); ++it) {
            if(*it == item) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    void erase(T const& item) {
        T* it = begin();
        T* const endIt = end();
        while(it != endIt && *it != item) ++it;
        if (it == endIt) return;
        copy(it + 1, endIt, it);
        --size;
    }

    // iterators
    T* begin() { return array; }
    T* end() { return array + size; }
    T const* cbegin() const { return array; }
    T const* cend() const { return array + size; }
};

class Vector {
private: 
    int x,y;
public:
    Vector() : x(0), y(0) {}
    Vector(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}

    friend bool operator== (Vector const& lhs, Vector const& rhs){
        return lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y;
    } 
    friend bool operator!= (Vector const& lhs, Vector const& rhs){
        return !(lhs==rhs);
    } 
};

#include <cstdio>

void VectorInM_Vector(m_vector<Vector> const& vec, Vector const& item) {
    if (vec.exists(item)) printf("Vector found in vector\n");
    else printf("Vector not found in vector\n");
}

int main(){
    m_vector<Vector> vec;
    vec.push_back(Vector(1,1));
    VectorInM_Vector(vec, Vector(1,1));
    m_vector<Vector> vec2(vec);
    vec.erase(Vector(1,1));
    VectorInM_Vector(vec, Vector(1,1));

    VectorInM_Vector(vec2, Vector(1,1));
    vec2 = vec;
    VectorInM_Vector(vec2, Vector(1,1));
}
```

[on compiler explorer/godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/sx1x84)

Comment: My new module should have been "int inline exists(const T &item)". Here is more scope to my problem. The code runs on QNX 4.25. std library is not used. The system is getting into some memory problems after about 8 hours of operation. I thought that if we could re-design the push_back call to only add unique vectors then we should be able to run longer. I'd also like to limit the code changes to avoid hundreds of hours of regression testing. I looked at the code changes above and it is difficult to detect what changes I really need to make "exists" works. Can you clarify.

Comment: Compiler error message is preceded by:  Error! E531

Comment: Using Watcom C++32 Optimizing Compiler Version 10.6 1989, 1996.

Comment: @billybob Wait what? This is *production* code? And you are using a compiler from 1996??? If this code passes the tests, then I'm afraid the tests aren't good enough. You can try to 'fix' the problem with this `exists` workaround. However, that will likely only change the MTBF time from 8 hours to 16 hours or so... That's not a solution. There are serious issues with the code, which will need to be fixed.

Comment: Yes, I know the code has some issues. I'm having trouble diagnosing due to lack of tools. I'm trying this as a debug approach to provide another data point in my analysis.

Comment: Fixed  my exists routine by changing "if(m_pArray[i] == item)" to "if(&m_pArray[i] == &item)". Compiles and code works. As JHBonarius indicated, did not help my memory issue but does provide me with another data point.

Comment: @billybob *"code works"* Please show me some test code that demonstrates that your code "works". In the mean time, [here's a demonstration that it doesn't work](https://godbolt.org/z/KzdE35). Congratulations, you've just made bad code worse. You should really do a C++ course or read a good book on C++.

Comment: As JaMiT noted, I did not include all the code. While I was reading up on C++ and staring at the code more, I noticed this routine inside the template: void erase(T& obj)
    {
        int iIn = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < m_iNextIndex; ++i)
        {
            if (&m_pArray[i] != &obj)
                m_pArray[iIn++] = m_pArray[i];
        }
        --m_iNextIndex;
    } I assumed that the "erase" routine was written properly so the "if (&m_pArray[i] != &obj)" approach would work for the "exists" routine. Sounds like my assumption was incorrect. Is that the case?

Comment: @billybob that `erase` function is indeed incorrect (unless used in a VERY SPECIFIC way). `&m_pArray[i] != &obj` is a comparison *by memory address*... which means it is only true if `obj` is literally referring to `m_pArray[i]`. Furthermore, there are a lot of unnecessary self-assignments in the function.
What I don't understand is: you mentioned you did hundreds of hours of testing... Why wasn't the code tested properly? This could have easily been found with good unit tests.

Comment: I see where I went wrong. The existing code only calls erase using the begin() as the input arg. Seems to work based on my stand-alone tests of vector.hpp. I guess I should attack this problem again after I brush up on my C++. Thanks everyone for your help, especially JHBonarius.